# how to use soap service in swift after converting wsdl2objc

Tags: ios, web-services, swift, soap, wsdl

Hi I am new to iOS app and swift and is having trouble figuring out how to use swift with wsdl web service. So, I have created some web service in a spring web app and is able to use the web service in some client in java. This is the example:

```
    GroupService service = new GroupServiceService()
            .getGroupServiceSoap11();
    GetGroupRequest getGroupRequest = new GetGroupRequest();
    getGroupRequest.setSearchString("abc");
    GetGroupResponse response = service.getGroup(getGroupRequest);

    for (RespondGroup rg : response.getRespondGroup()) {
        System.out.println(rg.getGroupName());
    }
```

Now, I want to use the service in my iphone app in swift language. First, I created the objective c class with wsdl2objc tools. Then, I got it to compile and able to use the classes in swift controller. However, I could not find an example on the web showing me how to use the service in swift. These are the classes I can call in swift controller.

GroupServiceService
GroupServiceService_getGroupRequest
GroupServiceService_getGroupRespond
GroupServiceService_respondGroup
GroupServiceSoap11Binding
GroupServiceSoap11Binding_envelope
GroupServiceSoap11Binding_getGroup
GroupServiceSoap11BindingOperation
GroupServiceSoap11BindingResponse
GroupServiceSoap11BindingResponseDelegate

And according to wsdl2objc document https://code.google.com/p/wsdl2objc/wiki/UsageInstructions which only shows how to do it in objective c. I should do something like this in swift

```
    var binding:(GroupServiceService)GroupServiceSoap11Binding

    var request:GroupServiceService_getGroupRequest
    var response:GroupServiceSoap11BindingResponse

    request.searchString = "abc"

    response = binding.getGroupUsingGetGroupRequest(request)

    response.bodyParts
```

Can someone show me how to used these objects in swift to do the same things as I did in the java client?

Or if anyone can points me to a better way of using wsdl in swift?

Thanks

Also, I got it working in objective C. This is the code:

```
- (IBAction)button {
    GroupServiceSoap11Binding* binding = [GroupServiceService GroupServiceSoap11Binding];
    GroupServiceSoap11BindingResponse* response;
    GroupServiceService_getGroupRequest* request = [[GroupServiceService_getGroupRequest alloc]init];
    request.searchString = @"123";
    response = [binding getGroupUsingGetGroupRequest:request];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self processResponse:response];
    });

}

-(void) processResponse: (GroupServiceSoap11BindingResponse*)soapResponse
{
    NSArray *responseBodyParts = soapResponse.bodyParts;
    id bodyPart;
    bodyPart = [responseBodyParts objectAtIndex:0];
    GroupServiceService_getGroupResponse *groupResponse = bodyPart;
    NSArray *responseGroupList = [groupResponse respondGroup];
    GroupServiceService_respondGroup *firstRespondGroup = [responseGroupList objectAtIndex:0];
     NSLog(@"%@", firstRespondGroup.groupName);

}
```

Just need someone to translate it into swift.

Answer (score 0):

I got it after some trial and error. Probably can make it look better. Anyway, this is it:

```
var binding = GroupServiceService.GroupServiceSoap11Binding()
var request = GroupServiceService_getGroupRequest()
request.searchString = "UVA"
var response:GroupServiceSoap11BindingResponse = binding.getGroupUsingGetGroupRequest(request)
var responseBodyParts = response.bodyParts
var bodyPart = responseBodyParts[0] as! GroupServiceService_getGroupResponse
var responseGroupList = bodyPart.respondGroup
var firstRespondGroup = responseGroupList[0] as! GroupServiceService_respondGroup
println(firstRespondGroup.groupName)
```